# How to find array in array and remove it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, find, matching

```
var arr = [["test","1"],["demo","2"]];

// $.inArray() ???
// .splice() ???
// $.each() ???

$("code").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

If I will find matching array by **"test"** (unique) keyword , I will remove `["test","1"]`

So `arr` after removed will be `[["demo","2"]]`

How can I do that ?

**Playground :** http://jsbin.com/ojoxuy/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is for:

```
newArr = arr.filter(function(item) { return item[0] != "test" })
```

if you want to modify an existing array instead of creating a new one, just assign it back:

```
arr = arr.filter(function(item) { return item[0] != "test" })
```

Modificator methods like `splice` make code harder to read and debug.

Comment: Great solution, but mind the requirement ECMAScript 5th Edition. And technically it always creates a new array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function remove(oldArray, itemName) {
    var new_array = [];

    for(var i = 0, len = oldArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        var arr = oldArray[i];

        if (arr[0] != itemName) new_array.push(arr);
    }

    return new_array;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var arr = [["test","1"],["demo","2"]];
var new_arr = remove(arr,'test');
```

I'm making assumptions here and not doing any real error checking but you get the idea.

Comment: Can I use  remove from `arr` , not make a new array ? , Thanks anyway

Comment: No not without altering the Array object. Check out Jorge's answer, `splice()` might be the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i][0] == "test") {
   arr.splice(i, 1);
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot about `splice()` :)

Comment: im so sorry but @thg435 is better answer :( , thanks anyway :D

Comment: @l2aelba Sure no worries. I agree `filter` seems more straightforward. Do note zeroflagL's comment on that answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
function rmEl(a,v)
{
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {

      if(a[i][0]==v)
      {
        a.splice(i,i+1);
        i=-1;
      }
      $("code").html(JSON.stringify(a));       
    }
 return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [["test","1"],["demo","2"]];

function checkArrayElements(a, index, arr) {
  if(a[0]=="test"){
    delete arr[index];
    arr.splice(index,index+1);
  }
}
arr.forEach(checkArrayElements);
$("code").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

NOTE: This removes any inner array in arr with the 0 element = "test"